# RewriteEngine On .htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my requests how I handle files like this

/r/login

but have that go to the server like index.php?r=login

This htaccess code that I am using does not seem to be working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/r/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?r=$1
```

If anyone could help me out, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code's problem is that you're using leading slash in RewriteRule. If used in .htaccess leading slash is removed by Apache. Change your rule to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^r/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```