# Apache ignores .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a debian apache server. For some reason apache ignores my .htacces file. Any ideas why this is happening?
Here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/default file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride none
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have also enabled apache rewrite mod.

Comment: that's all that in your default site file?

Comment: Nope this is the part i edit in order to enable .htaccess override

Comment: What is your document root?

Comment: /var/www . I updated my post and add the entire default file.

Comment: Ok did you restart apache after your made the changes to the default file?

Comment: Yes i did. I've even restart my machine but not working.

Comment: Did you check your error log? Check to really make sure it's not working and add random text to the top of the .htaccess file. It should give 500 error if it's not ignoring it.

Comment: When i add some random text inside .htaccess file it gives me a 500 error.  So my .htaccess file is not been ignored by my server. Thanks for your advice. Now i have to check what is going on and my pages are not rendered. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try adding `Options -FollowSymLinks` to the top of the .htaccess and remove the 3rd RewriteCond.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

Panama Jack thank you so much,

Based on your answer i find out the solution i was looking for. I added at the top of my .htaccess this line

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

that i found here
[RewriteEngine On .htaccess not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006502/rewriteengine-on-htaccess-not-working)

Thanks so much again!